# is that possible take data from web source page

Tags: python, html, dataframe, list, django-views

I'm playing Sorare and have live market shows that which user have which football player and when you did search 'X' player page shows all 'X' player cards and bottom of cards show that who own it. I found the class name of 'who own it2' part at source page but I don't know how to take every user name who have 'X' player on market then make excel schema

I try to take user name data because I'm try to build system that show who have 'X' and 'Y' player same time so I need to take data of username

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.